# I'm trying to create an object, but the code that should work isn't working

Tags: python, class, object

All Python learning that I have been doing shows that to create a new object, all I should have to do is define a variable and tell it what class it is. Most times when I do this, I get an error. What am I missing?

According to just about everything I've been reading or watching on the subject, the code below should work to create a new Railroad object. I have the class as a separate file, which I then include in the main program. The one time I have gotten this to work perfectly is when I created the object as part of a list instead of a stand-alone.

```
class Railroad:
def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Railroad"
    self.repmks = "RRRR"


#include Railroad

def create_rr():
    rr = Railroad()
    rr.name = input("Railroad name: ")
    rr.repmks = input("Reporting marks: ")
```

When this code runs, I get a traceback error telling me "name 'Railroad' is not defined." Did I not already define it as being a class?

Comment: You need to indent the `def __init__` method.

Comment: What does `#include Railroad` mean here? Are you expecting it to work like a C preprocessor `#include` directive? Python doesn't work that way.

Comment: If the `Railroad` class is in another file, you need to use `import` to load it.

Comment: @Alan: You need to [edit] your question to clarify it. As it stands, there is not enough information here for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Alan, learning Python you've missed two important subjects: imports and comments. Read about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing indent.
This part:

```
class Railroad:
def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Railroad"
    self.repmks = "RRRR"
```

needs to be:

```
class Railroad:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Railroad"
        self.repmks = "RRRR"
```

You probably need to return the rr variable inside your function.
Here an example:

**script1.py**

```
class Railroad:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Railroad"
        self.repmks = "RRRR"
```

**script2.py**

```
from script1 import Railroad

def create_rr():
    rr = Railroad()
    rr.name = input("Railroad name: ")
    rr.repmks = input("Reporting marks: ")
    return rr
test = create_rr()
print(test.name)
```

Comment: This is correct (indentation is wrong in the question), but it doesn't explain the error in the question, which is `name 'Railroad' is not defined`. If it were a matter of the indent being wrong there would be a syntax error instead.

Comment: Indeed, edited my answer to maybe fix his problem ^^ Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Honestly, the question isn't clear enough to know exactly. I suspect `create_rr` isn't the problem either, it's something related to `import` not being used (or not being used correctly). But rather than guessing at what might *maybe* fix the problem, the right thing to do is to wait and ask for clarifications on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Daniel, Barmar, and Igor - yes, I had mixed up my C++ dabbling with actual Python syntax and didn't import the files correctly. The indent actually wasn't the issue; it was indented in my program but not in the sample code.